# how to display the gridview on Page Load event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview

My GrdiView didn't show up when I try to run my program on a browser. My GridView has already a SqlDataSource, my only problem is how can i display it when I run it. Give some suggestions please. I dont have ay codes so far.

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: Do you bind the source to your GridView in the Page Load Event?

Comment: I dont have a c# code yet, only have asp.net codes so far. but my gridview is already have a datasource in it so it has a database already. it's just that it won't display on the page load. any suggestions is highly appreciated! @Kaf

Comment: how? can u show me? im a newbie in c# database. @Plue

Comment: Can you show the code where you load the SqlDataSource?

Comment: Have you verified that there is any data coming from the DataSource?  The easiest way to check is to add an EmptyDataTemplate inside the GridView (same level as the Columns object if you're manually setting columns)

Comment: i can't. im just at my phone :( i load my SqlDataSource on my GridView. @Plue

Comment: Yea. cus i have a TextBox where i could search all the items from it. when i type something on the TextBox It displays the rows of the searched item, im ok with it cus it's another thing. But my main concern is i want to display the whole database on page load. @JasonM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your asp.net coding it's difficult to help, but based on your comments it looks like you may not have bound your datasource to your datagrid. You will need something like this:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgMyGrid" DataSourceID="dsMySource" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MyColumn" HeaderText=" My Column">

        </TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</DataGrid>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsMySource" runat="server"  ConnectionString="<%$ Your Connectionstring %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM YourTable" 
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

As I say, it's a little tricky to help further without knowing what code you've done so far. You mention you've not done any c# so far, is your intention to do this in the code behind then? You can do that if you wish by filling a DataTable or something in the code behind page, and then doing something like:

```
MyGrid.DataSource = YourDataTable;
MyGrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: of course i really need to do this cus it's part of our activity. im getting it. i'll study and try this later. thank u! @sr28